# How to get the integer from sql database?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database with 2 columns, one of type int and other of type varchar.

When i try to get tha name with id=1 for example, the query works fine:

```
$name = mysql_query("SELECT Name FROM stations_id WHERE id=1");
$a = mysql_fetch_array($name);
echo $a['Name'];
```

I try to do the opposite but i cant get the integer value. For example:

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM stations_id WHERE Name='Mike'");
$a = mysql_fetch_array($id);
echo $a['id'];
```

I want to get the type as an integer so i can use it in a function.
Can somebody help me plz?

Comment: @Stepo the OP has provided what he have tried.

Comment: Can you explain what goes wrong, because at first sight the query looks ok

Comment: PHP doesn't really care if it's in a string, if you use it as an integer (`+` or `/` operators and such) it will work. Why do you care about it? (also why wont just cast it with `(int)`?)

Comment: The problem is when i do echo $a['id']; as in last command i dont get
any output :S
I dont know why.

Comment: If you don't get any output from `echo $a['id']`, then no record exists with a `Name` of `'Mike'`. On a development server, you should also increase your [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and turn on `display_errors`. That would have warned you about an "Undefined index 'id' ...".

Comment: Are you sure the name in the database is "Mike"? = is an exact match. Try using Name LIKE '%Mike%' and see if you get a result.

Comment: I made it work with LIKE. Thank you very much! The weird thing is that
the name is exactly tha same..I dont know why it didn't work with '='

Comment: Using `LIKE` when `=` should work is not a good idea. It means you have an error in your data which might have been introduced by an error in your code. I suspect trailing or leading white space in the `Name`-field of the record.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try to find the error in my data.

Comment: Oh, one last thing. If I want instead of '%Mike%' to put a variable, because the name would change all the time. How can I put it?

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need an integer, you have to cast `$a['id']` to integer yourself. This is, however, rarely necessary. If you use `$a['id']` in an integer context (e.g. in arithmetic operation) it will be cast to integer automatically.

Comment: The problem is not one of type. It's that no record exists with a `Name` of `'Mike'`. See the comment I added to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you do not have 'Mike' as name in your table

try:

```
$id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM stations_id WHERE Name like '%Mike%'");
```